# Cleaning Unnamed: 0, Unnamed: 1 index columns function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a bunch of datasets with an extra index column called 'Unnamed: 0', 'Unnamed: 1' etc and I want to make a function that removes these. My code looks like this:

```
def cleanDf(df):
    '''Remove unwanted index columns from df'''
    for col, row in df.iteritems():
        for i in range(len(df.columns)):
            if ('Unnamed:'+str(' ')+str(i)) == col:
                df = df.drop([col], axis=1)
            else:
                pass
    return df
```

When I run this on the dataframes however, the index column is still present but is changed to 'Unnamed: 0.1'. Why is this happening?

Comment: Two issues I see are 1) You should never alter a list or object while you iterate over it (iteritems+drop will generally give weird behavior) and 2) you don;t need iteritems here, since you're only operating on the columns and not the column index and the values. The `df.column` attribute is a much simpler way to handle this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or you could do this

```
df = df[df.columns[~df.columns.str.startswith('Unnamed:')]]
```

(which i've always thought was clunky, but oh well)

I guess you can `.loc` for it too:

```
df = df.loc[:,~df.columns.str.startswith('Unnamed:')]
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need: `for col, row in df.iteritems():`. Try:

```
to_drop = [col for col in df.columns if 'Unnamed:' in col]
df = df.drop(to_drop, axis=1)
```